# Smalltalk - Converting text object to string

Tags: string, smalltalk, visualworks

Hi I have text editor widget in smalltalk (visual works) that returns a text object, however I want the text returned to be handled as a string object.

How do you parse a text object as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `Text` and `String` are different classes in VW Smalltalk (which I don't have easy access to at the moment), see if you can call `yourText asString` or perhaps `String newFrom: yourText` or maybe `yourText as: String`.  Most of these would work in Squeak Smalltalk.

Answer (score 0):

You send #string to the Text object